# Shift and ergodic measures

Tags: functional-analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $X = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ endowed with the product topology and $\sigma : \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} X & \to & X \\ (\epsilon_n) & \mapsto & (\epsilon_{n+1}) \end{array} \right.$. It is known that $$\mathcal{M}_{\sigma}(X)= \{ \mu \in \mathcal{M}(X) \mid \sigma_* \mu=\mu \} \subset \mathcal{M}(X)= \{ \text{Borelian probability measure} \} \subset C(X,\mathbb{R})^*$$ where $\mathcal{M}_{\sigma}(X)$ and $\mathcal{M}(X)$ are both non-empty compact convex subspaces. Moreover, $\mu \in \mathcal{M}(X)$ is ergodic iff it is an extremal point of $\mathcal{M}_{\sigma}(X)$.

Is there an elementary way to show that such extremal points are dense in $\mathcal{M}_{\sigma}(X)$?

Comment: If you replace $\mathbb{N}$ by $\mathbb{Z}$, then the result you want to prove is an old result which says that the space of all shift-invariant Borel probability measures on $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a Poulsen simplex, but I do not know any references for this.

Comment: How "elementary" of a proof are you looking for? There's a proof at http://vaughnclimenhaga.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/notions-of-irreducibility/ which doesn't require any background beyond an introductory course on ergodic theory, but which is professionally terse. While I'd be happy to fill in the details as I understand them, the result would be a long answer by this site's standards.

Comment: Indeed, the proof is pretty elementary. You do not need to fill in all the details, but an expanded answer would be pleasant.